# How to block the chat window popup when i am playing swf game?

Tags: javascript, facebook-chat

User is playing a flash game.
When User's friend sent a message to user.
Some game's swf will hidden by facebook.
but some game's can block chat window popup,

how can they do it?
anyone knows it?

i see games below can do it.
http://apps.facebook.com/angrybirds/
http://apps.facebook.com/idleworship/

Answer (score 0):

When you embed your swf, you need to set `wmode=window`

Comment: Hi Fisch.
thanks for your answer.

http://apps.facebook.com/dazzling_club/
i set "wmode=window" , but it's not work.